# Razor Pages PageModel Initialization When Sharing Data Between OnGet and OnPost

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, nullable-reference-types, razor-pages

I'm trying to find the best way to initialize some `PageModel`, avoiding repetition and preventing nullable reference types warnings. Please see the below example. Is this the ideal way to initialize a `PageModel`'s data while sharing that data between the `OnGetAsync` and `OnPostAsync` methods? I still have issues with the Razor Page .cshtml thinking `Data` is null, but I don't see a way around that.

(I could do lots of work inside the constructor, which would fix some issues, but I don't want to do work inside the constructor for commonly understood reasons about keeping the constructor simple--not to mention that I can't use `async` in the constructor.)

I would appreciate some thoughts from some Razor Pages veterans. Thank you.

```
public class NewPageModel : PageModel
{
    private readonly SiteDataSource siteDataSource;
    public ModelData? Data { get; private set; }
    public NewPageModel(SiteDataSource siteDataSource)
    {
        this.siteDataSource = siteDataSource;
    }

    public record ModelData(SiteRecord Record, bool SomeBool, DateTime SomeDateTime);

    private async Task<ModelData> GetDataAsync()
    {
        int id = int.Parse(Request.Query["id"]);
        var record = await siteDataSource.RecordAsync(id);
        bool someBool = false;//Compute some bool
        DateTime dateTime = new DateTime();//Compute some DateTime
        return new ModelData(record, someBool, dateTime);
    }

    public async Task OnGetAsync()
    {
        Data = await GetDataAsync();
        //In the Razor page, use "Data" to write information to the page.
        //Unfortunately, this still results in warnings due to nullable reference types and the nullability of "Data."
    }

    public async Task OnPostAsync()
    {
        Data = await GetDataAsync();
        //Use "Data" to save data back to database.
        //Redirect back to page, triggering a GET request.
    }
}
```

Comment: use `BindProperty` attribute on `Data` property.